# Vlc how to output the audio to a second sound card by ignoring the default sound card of motherboard?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, fedora, vlc-media-player, arch-linux

While playing in Vlc any file/music/film. Using VLC configuration file, how to permanently tell VLC when-ever it plays audio use the second sound card or assign the name of sound card?

Example:

1. Motherboard sound card Intel (bad sound, VLC use default this one)
2. USB sound card Creative Live (better sound)
3. USB sound card Another brand

Goal:

Now when VLC starts to play any sound i want to tell VLC, play always, with the USB sound card  which has name "USB sound card Creative Live". not like hw:0,0 or hw:0,1 because the orders sometime get changed when system gets rebooted or usb gets plugged/unplugged.

Comment: If you change the audio output to ALSA and then choose your card through the GUI configuration dialogue and than check your `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc` file, you'll see that it actually stores a device name independent from the detection order, so setting it through the GUI preferences should be enough to achieve your goal.

Comment: @PedroRomano: i did that does not work, even volume=0 also does not work.